# how to extract get items out of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value, data-extraction

I have a dict that looks like this stored in a variable bookR

```
{'User-ID': '2345667', 'ISBN': '265838929355X', 'Rating': '0'}
{'User-ID': '2345635', 'ISBN': '3456477588844', 'Rating': '5'}
{'User-ID': '2345632', 'ISBN': '9890876776388', 'Rating': '4'}
{'User-ID': '2767888', 'ISBN': '2234566663200', 'Rating': '7'}
```

i want to extract two and store them in different variable as userA and userB

i have tried this but it gave keyerror code

```
print(bookR)

userA = bookR[1]

userB = bookR[4]

print(userA)
print(userB)
```

but the result i need is

```
print(userA)
output: {'User-ID': '2345667', 'ISBN': '265838929355X', 'Rating': '0'}

print(userB)
output:{'User-ID': '2767888', 'ISBN': '2234566663200', 'Rating': '7'}
```

Comment: You cannot store multiple dictionaries in one variable. There is either a list of dictionaries or a dictionary of dictionaries ... .

Comment: What you show at first, doesn't exists, that separate objects, they need to be contained on a list or comething, does `print(type(bookR))` show "class list" ? Or just share `print(bookR)` exact output

Comment: If the exception is KeyError then bookR must be a dictionary but you don't show how you've constructed that. If bookR is a list then you'll get IndexError when you try to access bookR[4] because the list would have to contain at least 5 elements for that to be valid

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

- each dictionary forms an **item** in the list called `bookR`

```
bookR = [{'User-ID': '2345667', 'ISBN': '265838929355X', 'Rating': '0'},    
         {'User-ID': '2345635', 'ISBN': '3456477588844', 'Rating': '5'},
         {'User-ID': '2345632', 'ISBN': '9890876776388', 'Rating': '4'},
         {'User-ID': '2767888', 'ISBN': '2234566663200', 'Rating': '7'}]

userA = bookR[0]
userB = bookR[3]

print("user A:", userA)
print("user B:", userB)
```

Output:

```
user A: {'User-ID': '2345667', 'ISBN': '265838929355X', 'Rating': '0'}
user B: {'User-ID': '2767888', 'ISBN': '2234566663200', 'Rating': '7'}
```

#### Note:

Lists use a **zero index**... which means the first item is at index `0`